# HeidiSQL doesn't see PostgreSQL datebases

Tags: postgresql, heidisql

could anyone explain why my HeidiSQL doesn't see created datebases with postgres?
To connect I've choose this settings:
Network Type: PostgreSQL (TCP/IP)
Library: libpq-10.dll
Host Name: localhost
User: postgres
Pass: the same as from install
Port: 5432.

Connection is success, but datebases aren't sees.
For example with extansion in VS Code I normally can reach the datebases with the same settings.

What I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

HeidiSQL can only connect to one postgres database within one connection and you need to specify the database you wish to connect to in the "Database" dropdown in the connection "Settings" tab in the Session manager. However after you open a connection to your specified database the name of the database isn't displayed and instead the name of the connection session from the session manager is displayed. Run the query `SELECT current_database();` to verify you are in fact connected to the DB you wanted.